# Huge text-file to mySql

Tags: mysql, text, large-files

Okay, so I have this utf-8 textfile containing 20 tab-seperated columns of various types (text, integer and date). The file has 2400000 rows (217Mb).

What is the easist way to get this file transfered to table in my mySql database?

Comment: Can you use the `mysql` command line interpreter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [load data infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Answer (score 3):

There are CSV import features in MySQL.

For e.g.:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html

And here is an example from one of the comments:

```
mysqlimport --fields-optionally-enclosed-by=""" --fields-terminated-by=, --lines-terminated-by="\r\n" --user=YOUR_USERNAME --password YOUR_DATABASE YOUR_TABLE.csv
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, found that the LOAD DATA INFILE statemnt worked easiser for me

Answer (score 0):

Best way is command line

If you have ssh access to the server, upload the file to server

login in with ssh then

then type
 1. mysql
 2. use database-name
 3. source ./path-to-file.sql

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-commands.html

and then wait a moment ;)